# Use Bootstrap affix in Colorbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, colorbox

My HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-16 scrollHeader" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="25">
...
</div>
<div class="content">
...
</div>
```

Its not working. So, i include affix JavaScript code in Colorbox function.

```
$(document).bind('cbox_open', function () {
            $(".scrollHeader").affix({
                offset: {
                    top: 10
                }
            });
    });
```

But still not working. When I checked it DevTools, not an error.

What's my problem? How can I solve it? Thank you.

Comment: What does 'isn't working' mean? What is your desired result? Also, col-16-16 is not a bootstrap class. Something along the lines of col-md-12 is.

Comment: Edited column. I want to sticky .scrollHeader class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Colorbox doesn't scrollable, you don't use affix option.